# Primefaces calendar default time

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In Primefaces 5.1, I need to set default time (23.59) in calendar control time slider.The time not specify to textbox starting only show in time slider then select date and time to show in textbox.

```
<p:calendar id="fromDate" value="#{calendarView.fromDate}"
pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" showButtonPanel="true" 
showOn="button" navigator="true"/>
```

Comment: As you can see in the answer, it is 'simply' setting the value in the backingbean…  just like with any other default value…

Comment: When I click calendar to show data and time in  a calendar. That slider time(hour and minutes) to I need to set default is 23.59

Answer (score 2):

You can set the value in the backing bean to the appropriate value:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.fromDate = getEndOfDay(new Date());
}

private Date getEndOfDay(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
    calendar.set(year, month, day, 23, 59, 59);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

[image]